# What is the nicest way to select the current week in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

At the moment I have something like this...

```
SELECT SUM(a.PaidSingle) AS PaidSingle,
       DATE_FORMAT(a.TimeIn, '%a') AS weekDay
FROM Attendance AS a JOIN MemberDetail AS m ON m.id = a.MemberID
WHERE m.CardNumber = '$cardNo'
AND   WEEK(a.TimeIn, 0) = WEEK(NOW(),0)
GROUP BY weekDay
ORDER BY a.TimeIn
```

But it dawned on me after writing it that this will take things from previous years as well as the current year.

I wanted to simply then say and year = thisYear but of course then on a week starting in December and ending in January I will only get half a week.

What is the best way to do this in MySQL or should I use a PHP based solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using WEEK with mode=0, which returns week numbers from 0-53 - that leads to a problem around new year, where part of the week
 might be 'YYYY53' and the rest 'YYYZ00' if you will.

If you could use mode 2 that would be compatible with the [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) %V and %X options:

```
DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ), "%X%V" )
```

These only use week numbers from 1-53, hence it's possible to get a week YYYY53 event for a date in year YYYZ.

Doesn't meet your requirement for niceness I'm afraid!

Comment: Answers my question perfectly, thank you! And it is far nicer than what I thought I was going to have to do.  About to implement and test but from reading the MySQL REF on it I can't see any issues.

Comment: YEARWEEK(NOW(), 2) I have found to also produce the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

why not select the weekday:

```
SELET DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%u')
```

as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Because this will still fail if I have Monday 15th Sept 2010 and Monday 15th Sept 2009 (or whatever the Monday of that week happens to fall in those years)

Comment: you can easily add the year as the link says, that's why I linked it